# CMake finding package configuration files but not the requested components of SFML

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I have been trying to build, and correctly set up Cmake with SFML using find_package + SFMLConfig.cmake.

Cmake correctly finds a configuration file (along with ConfigDependencies, ConfigVersion, ConfigSharedTargets) at default linux install location per [the SFML compilation instructions](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/compile-with-cmake.php#top):

```
/usr/local/lib/cmake/sfml
```

However at that path there is no shared library files (.so).
all of them (audio, graphics, network, system and window) are all the way up at:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

So i believe i have correctly built and "installed" SFML with make.
I get this error message (for all four components):

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake:150 (message):
Found SFML but requested component 'audio' is missing in the config defined in /usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML.
Call Stack (most recent call first):

CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package): Found package configuration file:
 
/usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake

  but it set SFML_FOUND to FALSE so package "SFML" is considered to be NOT FOUND.
```

I have tried to set the SFML_DIR variable in my CMakeLists.txt to many different places, both where i store SFML source (where i git cloned), where i built in to SFML-build. and where it is installed.
Why are the components missing? Should i copy the .so files into where the SFMLConfig.cmake file is? Should i move the SFMLConfig.cmake and update CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to a new path?

Looking into the SFMLConfig.cmake i see that the last if and elseif Statements in the code below is the one that fails. Meaning
TARGET SFML::${component} evaluates false. But I'm not sure what that means.

```
#SFMLConfig.cmake
    foreach(component ${SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS})
        string(TOUPPER "${component}" UPPER_COMPONENT)
        list(APPEND FIND_SFML_ADDITIONAL_COMPONENTS ${FIND_SFML_${UPPER_COMPONENT}_DEPENDENCIES})
    endforeach()
    list(APPEND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS ${FIND_SFML_ADDITIONAL_COMPONENTS})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS)
    [...]
    
        foreach (component ${SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS})
            string(TOUPPER "${component}" UPPER_COMPONENT)
            set(SFML_${UPPER_COMPONENT}_FOUND FALSE)
            if (TARGET SFML::${component})
                set(SFML_${UPPER_COMPONENT}_FOUND TRUE)
            elseif(SFML_FIND_REQUIRED_${component})
                set(FIND_SFML_ERROR "Found SFML but requested component '${component}' is missing in the config defined in ${SFML_DIR}.")
                set(SFML_FOUND FALSE)
            endif()
        endforeach()
```

This is my top CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/local/lib/cmake/SFML") # tell cmake where to find find.cmake and config.cmake files
set(SFML_DIR "/usr/local/lib")
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window system audio REQUIRED) # Look for SFML
```

Comment: At the top of `SFMLConfig.cmake` you may find the example `find_package(SFML 3 COMPONENTS Network System)` which uses **capitalized** component names. By reading other source code of SFML I found that exactly capitalized imported targets are created: `SFML::Audio`. Try to use capitalized names of components in your `find_package` call.

Comment: Indeed, @Tsyvarev is correct. I would also say that you are using current master branch of SFML -instead of latest release- which has introduced breaking changes in CMake config file (capitalized component names and namespaced imported targets), so documentation you are relying on is not compliant with the code you are using.

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thanks @SpacePotatoes for also clarifying why I had the wrong component names. This is actually the second time i have had troubles due to using master branch instead of 2.5.x, since as you said it have many breaking changes. So i went ahead and rebuilt using 2.5.x and everything works now.